# Calling different method depending upon variable's value without having an if-else block in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods

I have a variable `name` which can have one of the three different values: `"name1"` or `"name2"` or `"name3"`. Depending upon different value, I have to call a different value. For `"name1"`, I need to call `method_name1`,for `"name2"`, I need to call `method_name2` and similarly for `"name3"`, I need to call `method_name3`.

Currently, I do it like this:

```
if(name == "name1")
  output = method_name1(name)
elsif(name == "name2")
  output = method_name2(name)
elsif(name == "name3")
  output = method_name3(name)
end
```

Instead of having if-elses, how can I have a map of methods to apply? How to do it in Ruby?

Comment: A `case` statement is not substantively different than `if...end`, but it does read better with `case`: `case name; when "name1"; method_name1(name); when "name2"; method_name2(name)...end`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
method_map = { 'name1' => :method_name1,
               'name2' => :method_name2,
               'name3' => :method_name3}

send(method_map[name])
```

If the `name` is the actual method name, you could simply

```
send(name)
```

and if you can calculate `method_name` from name you could try:

```
send("method_#{name}")
```

If these methods have arguments - simply add them to the `send` method:

```
send(name, some, other, args)
```

Comment: How do I pass function arguments in this case? Lets say all those three methods take two arguments.